# Facebook share button only works the first time

Tags: html, facebook, compatibility, facebook-sharer

I am working on this website: http://www.annashome.com/site/index.php

I have a very strange problem. On each product's page I have a Facebook share button which works fine when using (or opening) it the first time but if you then go at another product's page and try to use it (share or just open) it brakes the URL (doesn't show title,description,image,etc.). I need it to show the title,image and desciption at all times.

If I clear cookies and try the button it works once again but not the second time on another product...

I have set all the attributes such as og:title, og:description, og:image and have checked the DOCTYPE but I still cannot figure out why it shows the correct info when using it for the first product but not the others.

I use addthis.com and have chedk it also. It's really bugging me.

I would really appreciate if you'd have some tips for me !

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the facebook share button works as it should - without any problems. You probably have an url rewrite problem or only a basic setting in the admin menu needs to be changed. Every product you have can be accessed from two different addresses. For example:

http://www.annashome.com/site/index.php/furniture?page=shop.product_details&product_id=16076&flypage=vmj_genx.tpl&pop=0

In this case, if you share it, the link will be broken.

http://www.annashome.com/site/furniture?page=shop.product_details&product_id=16076&flypage=vmj_genx.tpl&pop=0

In this case, it will work.

You can also see, that the share counter doesn't have the same number.

Your site adds this to your address on every product: "index.php/". If you remove it, everything will work as it should.

Hope this helps.